# Wake on LAN Settings

Tags: power

After all these years I have finally started playing around with turning on computer remotely. A Vostro 230 in particular. I use TeamViewer. The short question is ..... has anyone gotten Wake on LAN to work with a Vostro 230 when it is shut off?

The long question.... while I was working with tech support from TeamViewer they had me go in to Network and Sharing and set some advanced options on the Ethernet adapter. I asked they why ... because with the computer off these setting wouldn't affect the NIC would they? He actually wasn't sure. The only way Windows settings would affect a NIC on a turned off computer would be if those setting were stored in some kind of NVRAM on the NIC would it? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with Windows 8/10.  You need to disable hybrid shutdown (S4) for WOL to work, which Microsoft changed to be the default "Shutdown" option in Win 8 (the machine will boots faster from S4 than it does from S5). I got bitten with this when we first started rolling out Win8.  Here's a link to Microsoft's page on the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2776718

Comment: Here is where you get in to the finer detail. If I manually put the computer in to sleep mode TeamView does wake it up from remote. It will not, however, wake it up from a power off state. That would lead me to believe it is something else. WOL is enabled in the BIOS, I don't see an option to disable S4.I am under the impression that you are at the mercy of the BIOS and the mobo when the power is off aren't you? so the S4 issue wouldn't really come in to play would it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the Vostro 230 is with the age and the BIOS of the Vostro 230. Works fine with any other Dell more recent. Not an issue with 8 or 10.