# Restore CPU Scaling after Resume from Sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, sleep, scaling

Starting from boot, my computer responds to system load normally, with Windows 10 able to scale the processor speed higher or lower.

But, after resuming operation from Sleep, the computer seems to forget how to adjust the CPU frequency dynamically, leaving the speed in a low state and making the system sluggish.

[image: Task Manager: Performance]

### Additional troubleshooting thoughts

- I did have this problem while running Linux on this machine, and was
  able to correct it with [`wrmsr` from the `msr-tools` package](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1558932#p1558932):

  ```
  wrmsr -a 0x19a 0x0
  ```

  So, perhaps this issue doesn't lie with Windows, but with the
  hardware itself. I was able to find a reference to [`wrmsr` for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/wrmsr--write-msr-), but could not find on my system, even after installing [the Debugging Tools from the Windows SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/). It also did not seem to work when running `wrmsr` from a Linux Container in Docker.
- I am trying to interact with this computer headlessly, including
  using Wake-on-LAN (WoL) to resume from sleep. But, [from another
  question](https://superuser.com/a/1638995/45163), I learned that Windows considers resuming from Sleep
  via Wake-on-LAN an "unattended" event, so I am wondering if there is
  yet another hidden power setting that I am missing governing
  processor state after an unattended system activation. However, I
  couldn't find anything by looking at the output of `powercfg`:

  ```
  powercfg /L
  powercfg /Qh {GUID}
  ```
- I have [disabled "Fast Startup"](https://superuser.com/a/1152305/45163)
- I updated the BIOS to the latest version on 2021-04-28

How do I re-enable this performance scaling after Windows Sleep?

Comment: Try: (1) [Disable fast startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html), (2) Look for a BIOS update (let me know the computer model if you want me to help).

Comment: @harrymc: See edits, but I have performed both of those steps.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot when it happens of [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) of the CPU tab. What is the computer model?